# Null reference exception on wpf hyperlink click

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, vb.net-2010

I have a datagrid column which contains hyperlink and the  XAML for the datagrid column is

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Print">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate  >
                    <DataTemplate>
           <Button  Name="btnPrint" Click=btnPrint" >
                        <TextBlock >
                            <Hyperlink TargetName="_blank >
                               <Print> 
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                        </Button>
                      </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When I click on the button it gives me null reference excpetion. And, the  code for the button click is

```
Private Sub Print_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

   empid = DirectCast(Me.activeEmployeeDataGrid.CurrentItem, DataRowView)("EmployeeID")
   CreatePage(empid)

End Sub
```

I am getting exception at this line

```
    empid = DirectCast(Me.activeCrossingDataGrid.CurrentItem, DataRowView)("EmployeeID")
```

Can any one please point me in the right direction? Why am I getting a null reference exception?
Thank you.

Comment: Does the DataGrid *have* a `CurrentItem` when you make that call...?

Comment: Yes the datagrid have the current item

Comment: and the exception does not occur if i take out hyperlink....

Comment: Could you please add the full text of the Exception to your question, including its stack trace? It isn't clear what a hyperlink has to do with the line of code supposedly producing the error.

Comment: Thanks for your attention Dan. I changed the code to ` empid = activeCrossingDataGrid.SelectedValue ` and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this line of code

```
    empid = DirectCast(Me.activeEmployeeDataGrid.CurrentItem, DataRowView)("EmployeeID")
```

To this

```
    empid = activeCrossingDataGrid.SelectedValue
```

resolved the issue.